# Extract features based on spatial and attribute from another shapefile QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, extract

I have two line-type shapfiles A and B that have different sizes, but some of them go through the same alignment as the other. These two shapefiles have an attribute table with a column called `ident`.

I would like to extract the lines from shapefile A that pass in exactly the same alignment as B and have the same value for `ident`.

**shp A**

[image]

**shp B**

[image]

Line 1A is aligned with line 1B, but line 2A crosses line 1B (I don't want to). So I would like to extract only line 1A if it has the same `ident` value for both, that is, `ident`=1A=1B

Update: I added the files from question:
https://github.com/wesleysc352/wesleysc352.github.io/raw/master/files_1.zip

[image]

Comment: How many segments a line has? Just one ore it's variable?

Comment: each line is just one segment

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool. Set the **Input** parameter to layer **A**, and use the below expression for the **Expression** parameter.

```
aggregate(
    layer:='l2', -- set here the name of layer b
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=1,
    filter:=with_variable(
        'geom_a',
        geometry(@parent),
        abs(
            (y(end_point($geometry)) - y(start_point($geometry)))
            /
            (x(end_point($geometry)) - x(start_point($geometry)))
            -
            (y(end_point(@geom_a)) - y(start_point(@geom_a)))
            /
            (x(end_point(@geom_a)) - x(start_point(@geom_a)))
        ) < 0.1 -- set here the threshold, maximum slope difference
        AND
        attribute(@parent, 'ident') = "ident"
    )
)
```

I'm texting from my phone so maybe there are some parenthesis missing.

Comment: Important update.

Comment: I tested your algorithm, however it didn't filter as I expected. Actually it returns shapefile A as the original

Comment: @wesleysc352, Did you adjust the threshold to your data?

Comment: yes, i changed the threshold to 0.01 and also to 90 to test

Comment: where does the term `geom_a` come from? and why use the expression `aggregate:='count'`?

Comment: @wesleysc352. Answering to your second commentary of this thread, remember that the threshold is the slope difference between two lines. So 90 is a lot, I suggest you to set it between 0.1 and 0.5. For the last commentary, `geom_a` is a variable, see [`with_variable`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#with-variable). [`aggregate='count'`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate), if the count is zero that means that no feature matches with the filter.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you can use the `Intersect` tool to create a new shapefile that contains only the lines from shapefile A that intersect with shapefile B with shapefile A as the `input layer` and shapefile B as the `intersect layer`.

Use `Select by Attribute` tool to select only the lines from the new shapefile that have the same value for the `ident` attribute as shapefile B.

Finally use `Export Selection` tool to save the selected lines as a new shapefile.